# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

I'm facing an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
```

Code and Error screenshot:

[image: code and error screenshot here]

Can I know why I am getting this error?

I am trying to execute the script whose result should be printed as true, but gettting error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML, also properly formatted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To use the [**By**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class you need to import `By` as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```